# Why can't scala-ide refresh change in java classes in scala editor?

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I found a problem using scala-ide 2.1.0 m2.
I'm developing a java/ scala mixed project. When I add a method in java class and call it in scala. Scala Ide will report an error that the method doesn't exists. I tried  to refresh the project but I got no luck. I have to restart Eclipse(3.7 indigo) to let scala IDE load the updated java class.
Is there any way to let scala IDE recognize java changes without restarting eclipse?

Comment: Please [file a ticket](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets) with a detailed reproducible test case. OTOH, this should work without cleaning.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning the project works for me in same situation.

Answer (score 1):

Scala IDE is improving quite a lot lately. I had few problems mixing java and scala in one Eclipse project (generated by SBT, but not very relevant for this question) using the latest Eclipse IDE (Juno) and the latest version of Scala IDE.
I'd advise to download the latest version of Eclipse and and install the latest version of the Scala IDE.

Comment: I will give Juno a try, I am using latest Scala IDE, so I believe it won't make any difference under Juno. Anyway I will stick to ScalaIDE, I think it is good enough but with improvement little bit by little bit it can be the best.